# Getting the current user's session's name, IP address, name of the installed OS and the version of this OS in C++

Tags: windows, winapi

What are the *vocabularies* that I need to know to be able to get the current user's name, the name of the installed OS, the version of this OS and the related IP address in a C++ application?

**EDIT :** The solution will only run on Windows OSes.

Comment: It is operating system specific. Some OSes don't have windows, sessions, or IP addresses.... And I can use my Linux system without any windows or GUI.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, the app will only run on Windows OSes. I was talking about the user's name not a window's name.

Comment: Then please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Call the win32 api or some library like qt or boost that offers the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows:  [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [GetIpAddrTable (or a bunch of other APIs in iphlpapi.dll)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Unix: [getlogin](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin_r) [uname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) [getifaddrs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs)